# Rename Landsat bands across sensors in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, rename

I'm trying to rename bands with standardized names across different Landsat sensors. When I add layers using visualization parameters for the new standardized band names, I get errors like this: "Layer error: Image.visualize: No band named 'SWIR1'. Available band names: [B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, B11, BQA].", even though it appears the bands were renamed properly when I inspect the console. Any ideas how to fix this? Here's a link to the code I'm using: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d18d66c8b83cdbfe8121face2de964a

```js
//Collection filter parameters
var subset = Map.getBounds(true)
var start = '2019-12-01'
var end = '2020-02-28'

var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
ee.Filter.bounds(subset),
ee.Filter.date(start, end),
ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 70)
)

//Visualization parameters
var vis = {      
  bands: ['SWIR1','NIR','Green'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.5,
  gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};

// Assign a standard name to the sensor-specific bands.
var L8_BANDS = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B10','BQA']; //Landsat 8 original names
var STD_NAMES = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'Thermal', 'BQA']; //Standard band names
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA').select(L8_BANDS, STD_NAMES)// Rename bands

// Filter, sort, and print collection
var col = ee.ImageCollection(l8) 
 .filter(colFilter)
 .sort('DATE_ACQUIRED')
print(col, 'Landsat Collection')

// Display each image in collection
function addImage(image) { 
  var id = image.id;
  var iMage = ee.Image(image.id);
  Map.addLayer(iMage, vis, id);
}

// Use map on client-side
col.evaluate(function(col) {  
  col.features.map(addImage);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function addImage(image) { 
  var id = image.id;
  var iMage = ee.Image(image.id);
  Map.addLayer(iMage, vis, id);
}
```

When you do these steps, you're throwing out all information except the image's asset ID, and retrieving the original image by that ID — which has not had its bands renamed.

You could repeat the renaming on the fresh image:

```js
  var iMage = ee.Image(image.id)
    .select(L8_BANDS, STD_NAMES);
```

Or instead, you could look up the image *in the collection you modified:*

```js
  var iMage = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:id', id)).first();
```